# Highcharts: Add ONE custom label to yAxis

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts

I'm using highcharts and I know that the yAxis labels are automatically generated.

The thing is I've got this 3D graph in which apart from the data, there's a fixed 'goal' line on which we compare which data set is over or under it.

Since 3D graphs don't render lines very well, I used a plotLine and it works marvelous. The problem comes when I try to show how much this 'goal' is, because even though it's at the right position, it would be nice to display this goal amount.

What I want to do is display at the left of the graph the value of this line, so that whoever sees it is able to know how much the goal is for that particular data set.

Here's a screenshot of the graph, and circled the place I want to add the custom label: 
[Graph screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KtQqj.png)

Inside the red circle is where I want to add this custom string (which should be a percentage number).

I appreciate any help you guys can provide. Thanks!

Comment: I think that you should be able to use renderer.text for adding custom label to your chart: http://jsfiddle.net/0hyaevax/

Comment: @GrzegorzBlachliński thanks for your reply. That works well and I hadn't thought about using renderer text, was stuck thinking about yAxis labels. It works fine for the default view, but since my graph viewing angle is movable, the problem is it stays at the same place. [link](http://prntscr.com/fx8iab)

Comment: So you would like to achieve something similar to this example? http://jsfiddle.net/0hyaevax/2/

Comment: @GrzegorzBlachliński that's exactly what I wanted to do and it turned out perfect. Thanks a lot! If you wish to post it as an answer I could select it to close the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use renderer.text for adding custom text in your chart. 
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Renderer.text

```
  load: function() {
    var chart = this,
      yAxis = chart.yAxis[0],
      plotLine = yAxis.plotLinesAndBands[0],
      pLPath = plotLine.svgElem.d;
    chart.renderer.text('CUSTOM LABEL', parseFloat(pLPath.split(' ')[7]) - 100, parseFloat(pLPath.split(' ')[8])).addClass('cT').attr({
      fill: 'red'
    }).add();
  },
```

In the code above I am using plotLine's path.

Live example how your chart may work:

http://jsfiddle.net/0hyaevax/2/